# Why VS fails to bind rvalue reference to a pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rvalue-reference

Consider the following example (for hypothetical purposes):

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int *&&b)
{
    ++b;
    std::cout << *b;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1,2,3,4 };
    f(a);
}
```

To my humble understanding, the array `a` decays into an `int *`, which is temporary and thus an rvalue, and `int *&&b` should happily bind to it and extend its life for the scope of the function `f`. And this is what happens if I [run this with C++14 (gcc 6.3)](https://ideone.com/dT3JM4) and the result is `2`. In VS2017 however, I get an error:

> Error C2664   'void f(int *&&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int
>   [4]' to 'int *&&'

If I use `std::move` to force xvalue `f(std::move(a));` it also works in VS. Do I need to use `std::move` in this case or is this a some sort of bug in VS?

Comment: It's interesting to point out that GCC will happilly perform the equivalent operation with implicit casts, so I'd be inclined to trust VS for a change here: https://godbolt.org/g/oLZB4a

Comment: @Frank Your example compiles and runs in VS with no problem as well

Comment: I think the question boils down to whether a decay operation is equivalent to a static cast (which works on VS).

Comment: Note that VC does accept "f((int[]) { 1, 2, 3 });" with a warning about the cast being a non-standard type conversion syntax. And it makes sense that std::move() would be needed for f(a), if this conversion were legal without move there would be no point in having it.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I have 15.7.4 and `f((int[]) { 1, 2, 3 });` generates errors

Comment: @RichardHodges decaying array explicitly `f(&a[0]);` also works

Comment: What do you get beside warning C4576? I also have 15.7.4 and am compiling with warning level 4 and warnings as errors but I suppose it's possible I've turned off something else without remembering. In this particular case I preceded the f((int[]){1, 2, 3}); line with "#pragma warning(suppress : 4576)" so it only applies to the one call.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Yes, if I disable it `#pragma warning(disable : 4576)` (or suppress on the line before) it compiles but VS classifies it as an error for some reason

Comment: Oops, you're right, C4576 is an error not a warning, I am too used to C4* being warnings (and am blind so it didn't stand out that it's classed as an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program looks well formed and it is accepted by GCC and Clang.

It appears to be a bug in Visual Studio compiler, which manifested itself till compiler version 19.28 and was finally fixed in compiler version 19.29. Demo:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KbhGfhPbG